# EJNIFatal Exception : Method not found

Tags: android, delphi, c++builder

I got this little piece of code compiling, but when executing the TimeSinceBoot function in C++ code, an exception was telling me the Androidapi.JNIMarshal.pas file was not found.

Code :

```
unit SystemClock;

interface
      uses
        Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
        Androidapi.JNIBridge;
type
  JSystemClockClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{7C25E65F-A934-472E-A89E-C7F1DC10A292}']

   function _GetELAPSED_REALTIME: JLong;

    property ELAPSED_REALTIME: JLong read _GetELAPSED_REALTIME;
end;


  [JavaSignature('android/os/SystemClock')]
  JSystemClock = interface(JObject)
  ['{DC447EEB-147B-4A9B-B59F-2C84F959B2FD}']
  end;

  TJSystemClock = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSystemClockClass, JSystemClock>) end;

  function TimeSinceBoot(): Double;
implementation
  function TimeSinceBoot(): Double;
  begin
    result:= TJSystemClock.JavaClass.ELAPSED_REALTIME.doubleValue / 60000.0;
  end;
end.
```

I've found this file in these directories :

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\CatalogRepository\Android_Common_Files_Enterprise-18.0.Build.22858.6822\TARGETDIR\source\rtl\android
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\source\rtl\android

So I don't quite understand why Rad Studio couldn't link the file by itself.

Now, that I've added the file in the project's deployment files, when executing the function, I get the error :

> EJNIFatal Exception; Invocation Error : Method can't be found

It seems that my function make a call to this api even though I don't uses it, but it fails at finding the method it want to use ?

I wonder if the "method not found" is refering to the `ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `.doubleValue`.

I doubt that `ELAPSED_REALTIME` is a value but I don't get how to use the `elapsedRealtime()` function of SystemClock in the doc.

I'm currently using these links as references :

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html
>
> http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/1833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (a slightly modified version of) what Java2OP (which comes with Delphi) imports for the SystemClock class:

```
unit Androidapi.JNI.SystemClock;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  JSystemClock = interface;

  JSystemClockClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{771C5E34-6252-4BA7-8292-DD6BC82AA9B8}']
    {class} function currentThreadTimeMillis: Int64; cdecl;
    {class} function elapsedRealtime: Int64; cdecl;
    {class} function elapsedRealtimeNanos: Int64; cdecl;
    {class} function setCurrentTimeMillis(millis: Int64): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} procedure sleep(ms: Int64); cdecl;
    {class} function uptimeMillis: Int64; cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/os/SystemClock')]
  JSystemClock = interface(JObject)
    ['{6F88CF0F-2D6B-43D4-A23D-A04C1C56D88E}']
  end;
  TJSystemClock = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSystemClockClass, JSystemClock>) end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was stuck trying to use the same way my BatteryManager.pas does it. It works great.

Comment: @IDS if it solves your problem then you may want to consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: Stackoverflow tells me i need 15 rep points to count my upvote

Comment: Accepting an answer is different to upvoting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @IDS see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @IDS and now you have the power to upvote use it wisely.